# Is The Demon Slayer Anime Inspired By Quentin Tarantino's Movie Kill Bill?

Tags: demon-slayer

Well in some aspects of the show. it shares some few similarities of the movie and the anime of how they use Katana in fighting. While *Kill bill* is about a female assassin "Beatrix Kiddo" while the anime follows as Tanjiro, Nezuko and Inosuke.

Are they meant to be inspired?

While *Kill Bill* is a classic 2000s movie by *Quentin Tarantino* and *Demon Slayer* Anime series is a 2019 show

Comment: if i forgot something, please let me humbly know and i will add it in my post, Thank you!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think *Demon Slayer* is inspired by *Kill Bill*, or how they're similar? Right now, the only similarity you've mentioned is "they both have people fighting with katanas", which Tarantino borrowed from Japanese media - it's highly unlikely that *Demon Slayer* then copied it in turn **specifically** from *Kill Bill*.

Comment: I kind of share the sentiment with F1Krazy. Just a wild guess, but it's more likely to be inspired by any Japanese samurai stories, whether historical or fictional.

Comment: @F1Krazy I mean it's not only because they use the katanas but i only like the action in the anime the way they fight because in the moment it reminded me of the movie kill bill. But in some many respects im not say it's copied or was just it's inspired? so yeah it's a pretty cool animation with unique action with it

Comment: No. Gotoge revealed the top three manga that inspired Demon Slayer.

Said Gotoge:

“There are too many [manga] to count, but if I had to choose the top three, they’d be Jojo’s Bizarre Adventure, Naruto and Bleach.”

Comment: @Pablo i see. well thanks also for the answer! it's pretty cool anime yet it also reminds me of kill bill which is also a masterpiece!

Comment: @Pablo consider posting that as a proper answer :) might also help if there's a source/reference to back up.

Answer (score 3):

To answer this quite simply,

No. The anime, Demon Slayer is not inspired from Kill Bill. On the other hand, it is an adaptation of the manga [Demon Slayer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demon_Slayer:_Kimetsu_no_Yaiba) (as you might already know).

The long blade [katana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katana) is a part of Japanese history and culture. It was a traditional weapon of choice for the historic Japanese warriors (Samurai). While Quentin Tarantino can be said to utilise that particular Japanese element in his film, Kill Bill. It's illogical to assume that a Japanese series takes inspiration of a Japanese weapon from a foreign film.